# How to use Haskell Stack with Docker Compose?

Tags: haskell, docker, docker-compose, microservices, haskell-stack

I am trying to use docker compose to tie together some haskell services for local development. Most of the time I'm messing around in `stack ghci`, running unit tests, etc, but I also need to be able to run code that hits a dependency. Docker compose is great for this: I can run the dependencies (databases, other services, etc), and link everything together.

Stack has docker support. It can build in a docker container with `docker: enable: true`, and also can create an executable image with `stack image container`.

How do I leverage stack's docker functionality from within `docker-compose.yml`?

```
version: "3"

services:

  my-service:

    # how can I use `stack image container` here? Is it possible?
    build: '.'

    links:
    - other-service

    env_file:
    - test.env

  other-service:
    image: other-service-image
```

Do I have to make my own Dockerfile, or is there some way to use the `stack image container` functionality?

Follow-up questions: Is there some way to run `stack ghci` with all the settings (env, links, etc) from the docker compose file?

Comment: As far as I know, stack's docker integration does not play nicely with docker-compose (yet?), but take a look at the servant-docker stack template for an example of using stack + docker-compose. It does not use stack's docker integration, but has worked okay for me..

Comment: In the event it is helpful, here is an example project of mine: https://github.com/chrissound/ArchCompareTryCatchDeploy

Answer (score 1):

This only answers your follow up question (stack ghci within docker). Yes it's possible.

Depending what your service/container is named as (you can determine this with `docker ps`):

If your container is already running (via `docker-compose up` / `docker run`):

`docker exec -it directoryName_my-service_1 /bin/stack ghci`